# Java servlet shared object instantiation

Tags: java, servlets

I am creating a Java servlet that will need a shared object across all sessions (one instance for all connections).  I have read that this can be accomplished using getServletContext, however, is there a way to instantiate this upon webserver start up?  Currently I am using init(), however, this appears to be called upon each new connection.

Comment: you can use session but I dont recommend it

Answer (score 0):

I usually use a static variable. You can use the `static{}` initializer for more complex operations.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `ServerContextListener` and add it to your web.xml.

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>somepackage.MyContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

And:

```
public class MyContextListener implements ServletContextListener {

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        // Do init here - Occurs once when the context is created
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
    }

}
```

These methods are then called by the container when the context is created or destroyed, respectively.